AppleScript, Receiving System Error - System Events got an error: Cant get group 1 of window 1 of process "Mail". Invalid Index
Part of an AppleScript I'm using forwards an email and then places the cursor at the top of the body of the new message. The script works perfectly on my Mac running MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1. It also works on another user's computer running MacOS Ventura 13.6.6. However, the script returns the following error when ran on another user's machine running Ventura 13.6.9:
System Error - System Events got an error: Cant get group 1 of window 1 of process "Mail". Invalid Index
The portion of the code that is failing appears to be at the "tell first window" portion of the below code block:
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        set frontmost to true
        click menu item "Forward" of menu "Message" of menu bar 1
        delay 1
        tell application "Mail" to set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 1000, 1000}
        delay 1
        
        tell first window
            tell group 1 to tell group 1 to tell scroll area 1 to tell UI element 1 to set focused to true
        end tell

    end tell
end tell

Since this works on multiple machines, including one running Ventura, it feels like there is a system setting or permission that needs to be granted on the machine where the code is failing. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what setting/permission this would be. Any help in getting this code, or different code that accomplishes the same goal, to work on the machine running MacOS Ventura 13.6.9 is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Since it is not getting the first group, another thing to try is to increase the delay for the window.  Even though running the same OS, different machines with different running tasks can affect the timing.

What that error typically means is that the element in question isnt visible or available (or isn't something) at the moment that this particular line is asking for it. The script is confused about group 1, for whatever reason. One possibility is that Mail on that computer has a different layout or view.
